# OpenVPN - does it need public WAN IP mapping

Tags: openvpn

This is a small sample of my network Topology where I have a WAN Router <-> Switch <-> OpenVPN server.

I currently have limited number of public IPs assigned to the office.

My question is, can OpenVPN clients pick up my server to connect to using PAT through my router? Or does my OpenVPN server need a public WAN IP mapping (from the router) to be detectable from outside?

So for example, can clients connect only using 4.1.2.4(where OpenVPN server has that public ip address) or can it be 4.1.2.4:1001 where 4.1.2.4:1001 represents 10.67.0.1 from inside(where OpenVPN sever has 10.67.0.1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that OpenVPN Server simply runs on your machine, listening for connections on X port (in your case, 1001).

now, I am not completely familiar with CISCO equipment and terminology (PAT?), but I am sure that OpenVPN Server is ignorant to what brand your networking hardware is.

With that said, If OpenVPN is listening on 10.67.0.1:1001, you will need to forward a port on your Router, to a port on your machine (which resides within the internal network).

therefore, if you can forward 4.1.2.4:1001 to 10.67.0.1:1001, you will be able to connect to the WAN IP, and the signal will transverse the Internet, to your Local Network, and finally to the machine running OpenVPN Server.

Answer (score 0):

PAT should work fine, just configure your OpenVPN server to listen on the correct port.